# "Installing Ubuntu OpenStack: The Canonical distribution" failed due to bootstrap timeout

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am following the "[Installing Ubuntu OpenStack: The canonical distribution](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)" guide to deploy Canonical Openstack. My MAAS setup is already there and in healthy condition. However "*sudo openstack-install*" command fails due to timeout of juju bootstrap.

Now, I know that if I increase the timeout value in *".juju/environments.yaml"* by writing "bootstrap-timeout: 1800", I can avoid this error. However, the issue is that *"openstack install"* always overwrites the environment file due to which default value (600) remains there and issue keeps hitting.

Can anyone tell me about the file from which *openstack install* populates values of "*environments.yaml*" file? If you have anyother suggestion, please do write back to me.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try editting `/usr/share/openstack/templates/juju-env/maas.yaml`

Answer (score 3):

Issues with the OpenStack installer are tracked at the link below, please take a look, and if you can't find a match for your issue then create a new one.

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/